# Powershell Remote session and Git Credential Manager on Windows Server

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-remoting, git-credential-manager

I am accessing server via PS remote session. I am trying to run a `git pull` from a github repo. The git credentials on the remote machine are stored in Windows Credential Manager. However I get this error:

```
fatal: Unable to persist credentials with the 'wincredman' credential store.
See https://aka.ms/gcm/credstores for more information.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

This error occurs whether I use an interactive session or `Invoke-Command`. `git pull` and `git fetch` work fine when I RDP into the remote server and run the command there. Is there a way to access WCM in the remote session?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found an answer on this post :

[How do I disable Git Credential Manager for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-do-i-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows)

I don't need to cache credentials, so I just disabled it.